# auth2 Android Client how to save username logged after authentication

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

i've developed an android app; in few word i have a button called "login". When user click on it , it appaers a webview where the user write his username and password and perform the auth2 authentication. I want to save the username used in the auth2webview to display it in a  textview of my activity. How can do it?if is not possible, can i develop an auth2 autenthication without web view ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you obtain the OAuth token, you can verify this token and get user's account.
You can't develop an OAuth 2 authentication without web view.

Comment: thanks for reply! how can obtain user's account from token ? why can't develop oauth2 without webview ? i can develop the same action that do the web form ( get ..post..)..or no ?

Comment: Which OAuth implementation are you using? Google?